# IntegerUpDown ValueChangeEvent occurs every time I do keystroke

Tags: c#, wpf, integerupdown

When I using increment decrement with mouse, it works well. But when I am trying to write the value by keyboard, event handler reacts every keystroke. I triend to use UpdateValueOnEnterKey="True", but in this case increment decrement with mouse doesn`t react. How to make it work this way: when I click on increment/ decrement it should work instantaneously, but when I typing the value by keyboard it should work only after i press enter?

```
 <toolkit:IntegerUpDown x:Name="AnyName"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5, 2, 10, 2" 
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                       FormatString="N0" 
                                       ValueChanged="AnyName"
                                      />

private void AnyName_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (AnyName.IsLoaded)
        {
            string s = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, AnyName.Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems fairly logical to me. The user types, the value changes. What do you expect is going to happen as the user types? Why aren't you just binding the value?

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to use it properly. I tried to make it, but it didn’t work well

Comment: Why is an integer anyname? Name suggests string to me. Other than James Bond or the Prisoner maybe.

Comment: Does it really matter? AnyName is also string.